# PineScript: How to partial-exit a position without TP/SL?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I want to do a partial exit of my position (50%) on a condition that does NOT imply SL nor TP. How can I do it?

As I don't want to close my position, I don't use `strategy.close` but `strategy.exit` instead:

```
if condition 
   strategy.exit(id="long partial closing", from_entry="long entry", comment="partial close long", qty_percent=50)
```

Problem is, `strategy.exit` requires to specify a TP or SL parameter.
How can I go with only my `condition`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to do it with a condition, you should use `strategy.close()`.

> ```
> strategy.close(id, comment, qty, qty_percent, alert_message, immediately) → void
> ```

It has two arguments which you can use to close your position partially:

> ***qty (series int/float):*** An optional parameter. Number of
> contracts/shares/lots/units to exit a trade with. The default value is
> 'NaN'.
> ***qty_percent (series int/float):*** Defines the percentage (0-100)
> of the position to close. Its priority is lower than that of the 'qty'
> parameter. Optional. The default is 100.

Comment: Problem is, even if I specify a quantity parameter it will still close my position, which I don't want. I want it to stay open with its remaining 50%. I don't want to have to close it at 50% then open a new one, for fees reasons.

Comment: It should not close your position. There must be something wrong with your code.

Comment: Increase your order size via the settings -> properties tab and try again.

Comment: If you cannot manage to make it work, please share a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Indeed, problem is my position size was 1, I increased it and can now use strategy.close. Thanks!

Comment: No worries. For some tickers you must have at least one contract. That's why partial closing might fail on them.